# What's the equivalent of GROUP INTO in Linq extension method?

Tags: linq

This is how I'm filtering and grouping **transTasks**.

```
var transTasks = from t in taskData
                 where t.RangeName == rName
                 group t by t.CultureID into g
                 select new { language = g.Key, tasks = g };
```

Now I've a new requirement. Depending on the conditions, I'may  filter by **RangeName** or by **TaskOrderId**.

That's why I've transformed the above Linq code to the following;

```
var transTasks = taskData
                 .Where(predicate)
                 .GroupBy(???)
                 .Select(???);
```

I've researched but I can't still find the equivalent of **group into** for the extension method. I need to group those transTasks because there is a loop inside another loop.

Thanks for helping

Comment: `GroupBy` is the equivalent , and it seems you have figured it out.

Comment: I know this is old, but could what @Richard77 be looking for is the GroupJoin in the extension syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GroupBy` is the equivalent , and it seems you have figured it out, your query in Method Syntax  would be:

```
var transTrasks = taskData.Where(t => t.RangeName == rName)
                           .GroupBy(t => t.CultureID)
                           .Select(g => new { language = g.Key, tasks = g });
```

*As a side note, Any LINQ query in query expression compiles to Method Syntax.*

Answer (score 1):

```
var transTasks = taskData
             .Where(predicate)
             .GroupBy(t => t.CultureID)
             .Select(g => new { language = g.Key, tasks = g });
```